doubt on a limit of integral
i have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{ne^x}{1+(nx)^2}dx$, which i computed by putting $nx=u$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{n}\frac{e^\frac{u}{n}}{1+(u)^2}du$ by taking limit it gives me $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is this step allowed, how i can used dominated convergence here? and how we can solve it using elementary analysis only ?

$1_{(0,n)} \frac {e^{u/n}}{1+u^{2}}\leq \frac e {1+u^{2}}$.

which provides me only inequality

Use that inequality and Dominated Convergence Theorem.

If you feel comfortable with the exponential integral function, you could even show that it is $\frac \pi 2+O\left(\frac{\log (n)}{n}\right)$

okay so you are saying to use it as a dominating function, nice

Just for your curiosity
$$I_n=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{ne^x}{1+(nx)^2}\,dx$$
$$\frac{n}{1+(nx)^2}=\frac{n}{(nx+i)(nx-i)}=\frac {i n}2\Big(\frac{1}{n x+i}-\frac{1}{n x-i} \Big)$$ So, using twice the obvious change of variable
$$I_n=\frac{1}{2} i e^{i/n}
   \left(\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{i}{n}\right)-\text{Ei}\left(\frac{n-i}{n}\right)\right)-$$
$$\frac{1}{2} i e^{-i/n}
   \left(\text{Ei}\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)-\text{Ei}\left(\frac{n+i}{n}\right)\right)$$
Using asymptotics
$$I_n=\frac{\pi }{2}+\frac{\text{Ei}(1)+\log
   (n)-\gamma -e+1}{n}-\frac{\pi }{4
   n^2}+$$ $$\frac{-6 \text{Ei}(1)-6 \log
   (n)+6 \gamma +24 e-11}{36n^3}+\frac{\pi }{48n^4}+O\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^5}\right)$$ which is a very good approximation (relative error smaller than $0.10$% if $n>3$ and smaller than $0.01$% if $n>5$).

i appreciate your curiosity , rather heavy machinery for fun.

You had a good idea with the substitution: For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $u\in[0,\infty)$, let $$f_n(u):= 1_{[0,n]} \frac{e^{\frac{u}{n}}}{1+u^2},$$
then because of $e^{\frac{u}{n}}\leq e^1=e$  for all $u\in [0,n]$, one has $$|f_n(u)|\leq \frac{e}{1+u^2}=:g(u)$$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $u\in[0,\infty)$ (the inequality follows trivially for $u>n$ because then $f_n(u)=0$).
The function $g$ is integrable, since $\int\limits_0^\infty g(u)du = e\frac{\pi}{2}$, and so one can use the theorem of dominated convergence$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int\limits_0^\infty f_n(u)du = \int\limits_0^\infty \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(u)du,$$
where the limit under the integral is to be understood pointwise. Proving that this pointwise limit has to be $\frac{1}{1+u^2}$ is not hard: Let $u\in [0,\infty)$ be arbitrary, then for $n>u$, one has
$$ \left|f_n(u)-\frac{1}{1+u^2}\right| = \frac{1}{1+u^2}|e^{\frac{u}{n}}-1| \leq e^{\frac{u}{n}}-1,$$ which clearly tends to zero for $n\rightarrow\infty$ (as seen e.g. by the estimate $e^x-1 \leq ex$ for $x\in[0,1]$).

yes this part is clear now can you do it without measure theory, using simple analysis only.
